# matlab find() indices of cells for particle, 4-D double

Tags: matlab

I have the following problem.

Considering I have 4 Particles in one area.
The particles travel through this area with a certain velocity. At any given point in time, however, I want to know in which cell such a particle is located.

My sample code looks like this:

```
x = -10:1:10; % area
y = -10:1:10;

particle = zeros(1,2,1,4); % 4 Particle 
particle(1,1,1,1) = 9.5;  % x-position of the first particle
particle(1,2,1,1) = 9.5; %  y-position of the first particle
particle(1,1,1,2) = 7.25;  
particle(1,2,1,2) = 8.5; 
particle(1,1,1,3) = 6.25;  
particle(1,2,1,3) = 7.5;
particle(1,1,1,4) = 5.25;  
particle(1,2,1,4) = 6.5;

for xp=1:size(particle,3)
    for yp=1:size(particle,4)
        if particle(1,1,xp,yp) < x(1) 
            cell_x = 1;
        elseif particle(1,1,xp,yp) > x(end) 
            cell_x = size(x,2);
        else 
            cell_x = find(x <= particle(1,1,xp,yp),1,'last');
        end
        if particle(1,2,xp,yp) < y(1) 
            cell_y = 1;
        elseif particle(1,2,xp,yp) > y(end)
            cell_y = size(y,2);
        else
            cell_y = find(y <= particle(1,2,xp,yp),1,'last'); 
        end
    end
end
```

My code takes too long for a number of 52 x 10 particles. I wanted to omit a for loop by entering `yp` as an array in `particle(1,2,xp,yp)`, but unfortunately the `find()` function can't handle arrays. Or am I wrong? Do you have an idea how to make it work much faster so that I have

```
cell_x = [20,18,17,16]
cell_y = [20,19,18,17]
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you are searching  `find(x <= particle(1,1,xp,yp),1,'last')` for the index and not apply a transformation of the saved x-position. E.g: In your example `x` takes values between -10 and 10 in steps of 1, you could just use floor of the saved value and offset it to get the index? This way you would omit a loop. You just need to know which transformation on the saved `x`or `y` coordinate you need to perform to get the index

Comment: In my original code I have `x=linspace(-0.0800,0.0134,nx)` and my step is depending on `dx  = (0.08+0.0134) / (nx-1);` with `nx=100`. So I don't see the use of floor. But I can also be wrong.

Comment: `linspace` produces linearly spaced x values, so you only need to know the step size and the minimum of your array, see the end of  my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example code to my comment

```
x = -10:1:10; % area x

%input data 
Numberofdata=4;
saved_x=[9.5 7.25 6.25 5.25];

%conversion from value to index
idx_x1=floor(saved_x)+abs(min(x))+1;
%search for index
for k=1:Numberofdata
idx_x2(k,1)=find(x <=saved_x(k),1,'last');
end

%    Output
[idx_x1' idx_x2]

20    20
18    18
17    17
16    16
```

I know it is applied to a vector and not a matrix however, you can apply this transformation to any dimension of your Matrix.

In the case you are not changing `x` in steps of 1 but something like that:

```
x=min_x:dx:max_x
```

then the you need to do the following:

```
idx_x1=floor(saved_x/dx)+abs(min_x/dx)+1;
```

Comment: That's looks really great. Thank you. I have to test it right now.